# How to include nav bar, banner and logo in same div

Tags: html, css, banner

I want to have the nav bar and logo overlayed on the same banner image. It should look something like this:

[image]

Here's my shoddy HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<title>Banner and Navigation menu</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header-container">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
            <a href="#"><img src="Logo.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="Nav menu Comic.jpeg" alt="home" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="Nav menu mashups" alt="about" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="Nav menu store" alt="services" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/products.png" alt="products" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/contact.png" alt="contact" /></a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my css:

```
    @charset "utf-8";
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#header-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 204px;
    background-color: #0071b2;
}

#header {
    background-image:  <img src= homepage url(../Website%20pictures/homepage%20banner.jpg)> </img> ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 204px;
    margin: auto;
}

#logo {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 170px;
    padding-top: 35px;
}

img {
    border: none;
}

#nav {
    height: 76px;
    width: 1024px;
    padding-top: 152px;
    padding-left: 158px;
}

#nav ul
{
    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1024px;
}

#nav ul li
{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}/* CSS Document */
```

I've been struggling to get my background image to display as well.

Comment: This should help: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Do you have any example code that you're working with? That might give everyone a better idea of what you're trying to do. But essentially, I think you could either set the banner image as a background image of the div that contains the nav bar and logo. OR, you could set the banner div position to relative, and then set the nav bar, and logo to position absolute, and overlay them ontop.

Comment: Done my best to clarify

Answer (score 2):

To get the background image working you need to change the background-image attribute.

Wrong:

```
background-image:  <img src= homepage url(../Website%20pictures/homepage%20banner.jpg)> </img> ;
```

Correct:

```
background-image: url("../Website pictures/homepage banner.jpg");
```

By the way, it is not a good practice to use spaces in file names. Consider using `../Website-pictures/homepage-banner.jpg` instead.

Comment: and yet, i'm still left with a blue background no image.

Comment: Thanks, but still nought. My nav menu has suddenly turned vertical instead of horizontal though.

Comment: Are you sure the image is in that folder?

Comment: Certain. On the other hand, I'm using Dreamweaver and it has a habit of failing to show my images unless I select them in the design view.

Comment: After selecting I choose the image to display again, and I can't seem to select the background image in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Just needed to rename the nav ul + li to logo ul + li.